# Monitor a log file using tail -f

Tags: bash, shell, logging

Need some guidance

Monitor a application log file(log rotation is daily)using tail-f, if exception in log file need to send alert using script.

Comment: Without more context and / or code sample of what you tried, you most likely won't get any answer. For starters, I suggest running a cronjob to recover your logs, and run your analysis script right after that.

Comment: I am new to this enviroment, i wanted to monitor a application log file, which rotation is daily, and see if there's any exception it should send some notification.

How do i proceeds with this?

Comment: have a look at `cron` to set a specific task at a specific time of day, and `awk`, `grep` or `sed` to analyse the content of a file according to a pattern

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to build a log monitor with just `tail -f`.  `tail` does have a `+c` option to read from a particular position, but it would be tricky to build good code around it.

What you need is this:

- a read control file that stores the last byte position read from the log file
- a script that uses the read control file to do incremental reads (using `seek`) and does pattern matching and notification based on the lines read, and updates the read control file
- the inode number could be used for naming the read control file so that the incremental logic continues to work even if the log file is renamed or moved

The above script could either run as a daemon or execute periodically as a cron job.  I would strongly suggest using Perl, Ruby, Python, or even Java/C/C++ for this.