# How can I process a dynamically growing big file in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sed, file-processing

I have a very big file in my Linux server(currently more than 10GB) and the content is keep on adding to the end of the file .

I have another script that needs to process this file about 1000 lines at a time . What is the best way to get the lines from this file and operate on the same .

I am thinking about sed command to cut out the lines. But is that the best approach ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42396561/monitor-a-log-file-using-tail-f/42398092#42398092

Comment: @codeforester thanks for the link .But I am not sure how to implement this for a huge file using shell script

Comment: That's exactly my point.  You are far better using a more advanced language like Ruby, Python, or Perl for it.  I have solved such problems with Perl / C in the past.  Bash is definitely not the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Since the file to be monitored is a plain text file (not binary), you could do a

```
tail -f my_big_fat_file | my_fancy_processing_script
```

You don't get it in 1000-line-chunks, but your processing script can accumulate the lines and start processing until it collected enough of them.

Comment: This seems not working .  I am getting the command got exited immediately

Comment: There are two possibilities that this commands exits immediately (and in each case you will get an error message): (1) The file does not exist yet at the time you invoke the command, or (2) Your script closes STDIN. I don't see how this command could terminate siltently.

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -n 1 -f growingfile.log | while read line; do
   echo $line
done
```

`tail -n 1 -f <file>` will print out the last line in the file and will keep printing out each new line appended to the file. That output is piped to `while read line` that will be able to process each new line written to the file